# Usage npm command after any command entered

Tags: node.js, npm

i'm using cmder in win8.1. I have install node.js with npm. I have created alias for npm in cmder and when i am trying to check if it's ok, i use `npm --version` all i get is

```
npm config help

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\svrcek\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@1.4.3 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Can someone help me where may be problem? All i found is that this is shown when invalid command is inserted, but i think it is valid

Comment: How did you add the alias? Why do you need one in the first place? Does `npm --version` work at a normal command prompt?

Comment: @mscdex `alias npm="C:\Program~2\nodejs\npm.cmd"` and why i need it? because before npm --version return, that it is not recognized

Comment: what is the solution here.. i have a same problem. but not understand the below solutiion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this alias:

`alias npm=C:\Progra~2\nodejs\npm.cmd $*` if you have "Program Files (x86)" or
`alias npm=C:\Progra~1\nodejs\npm.cmd $*` if you have just "Program Files".

Comment: Yes, this make it work :) thanks, can i ask to understand, what is the difference between `alias npm="C:\Program~2\nodejs\npm.cmd"` and `alias npm=C:\Progra~2\nodejs\npm.cmd $*`

Comment: I get `'alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command` on windows I had to change alias to `doskey` the command is ok but I still get the above error. Any suggestions? @donuttello

Comment: @Mahsa you should try to use PowerShell on OS Windows